# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.grid_search'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing an image detection problem but, I got some errors while I import `RandomizedSearchCV`.

I have installed:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
pip3 install scikit-image
```

I tried this code first:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

its worked, After that, I import `RandomizedSearchCV` like this, and its showing error.

```
from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklaern.cross_validation import train_test_split


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9f5ecfd22091> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV
      2 from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
      3 from sklaern.cross_validation import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.grid_search'

 >>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.20.3'
```

Answer (score 36):

In recent versions, these modules are now under `sklearn.model_selection`, and not any more under `sklearn.grid_search`, and the same holds true for `train_test_split` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection)); so, you should change your imports to:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

or more concisely

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV, train_test_split
```